# Help with instancing: seg fault with glVertexAttribDivisor

Tags: opengl, instancing

I'm trying to get the basics of instancing in OpenGL 3.3 and failing miserably. I'm starting with the [Jason McKesson's Depth Buffering tutorial](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut05%20Overlap%20and%20Depth%20Buffering.html), then modifying it so that only the horizontally-oriented object is drawn, but it should be drawn twice using `glDrawElementsInstanced()` with different offsets.

The key problem I'm running into is that I get a segmentation fault when I call `glVertexAttribDivisor()`. I've tried with both the attribute I've added to the tutorial, and when I try to use this function to set a divisor of 0 for the two attributes that were already used in the original tutorial code.

I tried modifying one of the other source files from the same tutorial so that the ONLY change was to call `glVertexAttribDivisor()` to set an attribute's divisor to 0, and it seg faulted too. I'll post my code below, but I suspect there's a compilation flag that makes instancing not work, or else I need to call this function before an attribute has been enabled, or something. Any ideas?

DepthBuffer.cpp:

```
//Copyright (C) 2010-2012 by Jason L. McKesson
//This file is licensed under the MIT License.



#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <glload/gl_3_3.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include "../framework/framework.h"

#define ARRAY_COUNT( array ) (sizeof( array ) / (sizeof( array[0] ) * (sizeof( array ) != sizeof(void*) || sizeof( array[0] ) <= sizeof(void*))))

GLuint theProgram;

//GLuint offsetUniform;
GLuint perspectiveMatrixUnif;

float perspectiveMatrix[16];
const float fFrustumScale = 1.0f;

void InitializeProgram()
{
        std::vector<GLuint> shaderList;

        shaderList.push_back(Framework::LoadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "Standard.vert"));
        shaderList.push_back(Framework::LoadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "Standard.frag"));

        theProgram = Framework::CreateProgram(shaderList);

        //offsetUniform = glGetUniformLocation(theProgram, "offset");

        perspectiveMatrixUnif = glGetUniformLocation(theProgram, "perspectiveMatrix");

        float fzNear = 1.0f; float fzFar = 3.0f;

        memset(perspectiveMatrix, 0, sizeof(float) * 16);

        perspectiveMatrix[0] = fFrustumScale;
        perspectiveMatrix[5] = fFrustumScale;
        perspectiveMatrix[10] = (fzFar + fzNear) / (fzNear - fzFar);
        perspectiveMatrix[14] = (2 * fzFar * fzNear) / (fzNear - fzFar);
        perspectiveMatrix[11] = -1.0f;

        glUseProgram(theProgram);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(perspectiveMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE, perspectiveMatrix);
        glUseProgram(0);
}

const int numberOfVertices = 36;

#define RIGHT_EXTENT 0.8f
#define LEFT_EXTENT -RIGHT_EXTENT
#define TOP_EXTENT 0.20f
#define MIDDLE_EXTENT 0.0f
#define BOTTOM_EXTENT -TOP_EXTENT
#define FRONT_EXTENT -1.25f
#define REAR_EXTENT -1.75f

#define GREEN_COLOR 0.75f, 0.75f, 1.0f, 0.5f
#define BLUE_COLOR  0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f
#define RED_COLOR 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f
#define GREY_COLOR 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.5f
#define BROWN_COLOR 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f

const float vertexData[] = {
        //Object 1 positions
        LEFT_EXTENT,  TOP_EXTENT,   REAR_EXTENT,
        LEFT_EXTENT,  MIDDLE_EXTENT,  FRONT_EXTENT,
        RIGHT_EXTENT, MIDDLE_EXTENT,  FRONT_EXTENT,
        RIGHT_EXTENT, TOP_EXTENT,   REAR_EXTENT,

        LEFT_EXTENT,  BOTTOM_EXTENT,  REAR_EXTENT,
        LEFT_EXTENT,  MIDDLE_EXTENT,  FRONT_EXTENT,
        RIGHT_EXTENT, MIDDLE_EXTENT,  FRONT_EXTENT,
        RIGHT_EXTENT, BOTTOM_EXTENT,  REAR_EXTENT,

        LEFT_EXTENT,  TOP_EXTENT,   REAR_EXTENT,
        LEFT_EXTENT,  MIDDLE_EXTENT,  FRONT_EXTENT,
        LEFT_EXTENT,  BOTTOM_EXTENT,  REAR_EXTENT,

        RIGHT_EXTENT, TOP_EXTENT,   REAR_EXTENT,
        RIGHT_EXTENT, MIDDLE_EXTENT,  FRONT_EXTENT,
        RIGHT_EXTENT, BOTTOM_EXTENT,  REAR_EXTENT,

        LEFT_EXTENT,  BOTTOM_EXTENT,  REAR_EXTENT,
        LEFT_EXTENT,  TOP_EXTENT,   REAR_EXTENT,
        RIGHT_EXTENT, TOP_EXTENT,   REAR_EXTENT,
        RIGHT_EXTENT, BOTTOM_EXTENT,  REAR_EXTENT,

        //Object 2 positions
        TOP_EXTENT,   RIGHT_EXTENT, REAR_EXTENT,
        MIDDLE_EXTENT,  RIGHT_EXTENT, FRONT_EXTENT,
        MIDDLE_EXTENT,  LEFT_EXTENT,  FRONT_EXTENT,
        TOP_EXTENT,   LEFT_EXTENT,  REAR_EXTENT,

        BOTTOM_EXTENT,  RIGHT_EXTENT, REAR_EXTENT,
        MIDDLE_EXTENT,  RIGHT_EXTENT, FRONT_EXTENT,
        MIDDLE_EXTENT,  LEFT_EXTENT,  FRONT_EXTENT,
        BOTTOM_EXTENT,  LEFT_EXTENT,  REAR_EXTENT,

        TOP_EXTENT,   RIGHT_EXTENT, REAR_EXTENT,
        MIDDLE_EXTENT,  RIGHT_EXTENT, FRONT_EXTENT,
        BOTTOM_EXTENT,  RIGHT_EXTENT, REAR_EXTENT,

        TOP_EXTENT,   LEFT_EXTENT,  REAR_EXTENT,
        MIDDLE_EXTENT,  LEFT_EXTENT,  FRONT_EXTENT,
        BOTTOM_EXTENT,  LEFT_EXTENT,  REAR_EXTENT,

        BOTTOM_EXTENT,  RIGHT_EXTENT, REAR_EXTENT,
        TOP_EXTENT,   RIGHT_EXTENT, REAR_EXTENT,
        TOP_EXTENT,   LEFT_EXTENT,  REAR_EXTENT,
        BOTTOM_EXTENT,  LEFT_EXTENT,  REAR_EXTENT,

        //Object 1 colors
        GREEN_COLOR,
        GREEN_COLOR,
        GREEN_COLOR,
        GREEN_COLOR,

        BLUE_COLOR,
        BLUE_COLOR,
        BLUE_COLOR,
        BLUE_COLOR,

        RED_COLOR,
        RED_COLOR,
        RED_COLOR,

        GREY_COLOR,
        GREY_COLOR,
        GREY_COLOR,

        BROWN_COLOR,
        BROWN_COLOR,
        BROWN_COLOR,
        BROWN_COLOR,

        //Object 2 colors
        RED_COLOR,
        RED_COLOR,
        RED_COLOR,
        RED_COLOR,

        BROWN_COLOR,
        BROWN_COLOR,
        BROWN_COLOR,
        BROWN_COLOR,

        BLUE_COLOR,
        BLUE_COLOR,
        BLUE_COLOR,

        GREEN_COLOR,
        GREEN_COLOR,
        GREEN_COLOR,

        GREY_COLOR,
        GREY_COLOR,
        GREY_COLOR,
        GREY_COLOR,
};

const GLshort indexData[] =
{
        0, 2, 1,
        3, 2, 0,

        4, 5, 6,
        6, 7, 4,

        8, 9, 10,
        11, 13, 12,

        14, 16, 15,
        17, 16, 14,
};

GLuint vertexBufferObject;
GLuint indexBufferObject;
GLuint offsetBufferObject;
GLuint vao;

const float offsetData[] = {
        //Object 1 offset
  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

      // Object 2 offset
  0.0f, 0.5f, -0.25f,
};

void InitializeVertexBuffer()
{
        glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObject);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferObject);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferObject);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indexData), indexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glGenBuffers(1, &offsetBufferObject);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offsetBufferObject);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(offsetData), offsetData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

//Called after the window and OpenGL are initialized. Called exactly once, before the main loop.
void init()
{
        InitializeProgram();
        InitializeVertexBuffer();

        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        size_t colorDataOffset = sizeof(float) * 3 * numberOfVertices;
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)colorDataOffset);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offsetBufferObject);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(0, 0);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(1, 0);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferObject);

        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glCullFace(GL_BACK);
        glFrontFace(GL_CW);

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
        glDepthRange(0.0f, 1.0f);
}

//Called to update the display.
//You should call glutSwapBuffers after all of your rendering to display what you rendered.
//If you need continuous updates of the screen, call glutPostRedisplay() at the end of the function.
void display()
{
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClearDepth(1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(theProgram);

        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, ARRAY_COUNT(indexData), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0, 2);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glUseProgram(0);

        glutSwapBuffers();
}

//Called whenever the window is resized. The new window size is given, in pixels.
//This is an opportunity to call glViewport or glScissor to keep up with the change in size.
void reshape (int w, int h)
{
        perspectiveMatrix[0] = fFrustumScale * (h / (float)w);
        perspectiveMatrix[5] = fFrustumScale;

        glUseProgram(theProgram);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(perspectiveMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE, perspectiveMatrix);
        glUseProgram(0);

        glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
}

//Called whenever a key on the keyboard was pressed.
//The key is given by the ''key'' parameter, which is in ASCII.
//It's often a good idea to have the escape key (ASCII value 27) call glutLeaveMainLoop() to 
//exit the program.
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
        switch (key)
        {
        case 27:
                glutLeaveMainLoop();
                return;
        }
}


unsigned int defaults(unsigned int displayMode, int &width, int &height) {return displayMode;}
```

Standard.vert (vertex shader):

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 offset;

smooth out vec4 theColor;

//uniform vec3 offset;
uniform mat4 perspectiveMatrix;

void main()
{
        vec4 cameraPos = position + vec4(offset.x, offset.y, offset.z, 0.0);

        gl_Position = perspectiveMatrix * cameraPos;
        theColor = color;
}
```

UPDATE: I checked the value of `glVertexAttribDivisor` in gdb (as well as `glVertexAttribPointer` for comparison), and I think it looks valid:

```
(gdb) p glVertexAttribDivisor
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x7ffff7bc3000 <glVertexAttribDivisorARB>
(gdb) p glVertexAttribPointer
$2 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x7ffff7bc2900 <glVertexAttribPointerARB>
```

Comment: The normal reason for OpenGL segfaults is that the function being called has not actually been loaded, in this case meaning that `glVertexAttribDivisor` is `NULL`. If you haven't checked this then this is a good place to start.

Comment: @Anton This doesn't seem to be the case. I added the output from GDB above.